# Posterior probability - change in Beta hyperparameters

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, beta-distribution, posterior

Can you explain, how does $\text{B}(\alpha, \beta)$ transfrom to $\text{B}(s+\alpha, f+\beta)$ in the following equation?

$$
\begin{align*}
p(\left. q=x \right| s,f)
&= {{{s+f \choose s} x^{s+\alpha-1}(1-x)^{f+\beta-1} / \operatorname{B}(\alpha,\beta)} \over  \int_{y=0}^1 \left({s+f \choose s} y^{s+\alpha-1}(1-y)^{f+\beta-1} / \operatorname{B}(\alpha,\beta)\right) dy} \\
~\\
~\\
~\\
~\\
& = {x^{s+\alpha-1}(1-x)^{f+\beta-1} \over \operatorname{B}(s+\alpha,f+\beta)}
\end{align*}
$$
(This equation is taken from [Wikipedia's article on conjugate priors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior).)

However, I started an investigation from parameter estimation for text analysis by G. Heinrich (in that paper, equations 23 and 24).

I see, that in many papers, this is an "of course" statement, but I would be grateful for a derivation of the formula, or hints on how to do it on my own.

Comment: Full reference for Heinrich paper please: are you expecting people to Google it themselves?

Comment: **No math whatsoever is needed** (which is why this is an "of course" result): notice that only the numerator depends on $x$ and that the $x$-dependence is accounted for entirely by the terms $x^{s+\alpha-1}(1-x)^{f+\beta-1}$ (whose values are defined and non-negative only for $0\le x\le 1$). *Every bit* of the rest is a constant and therefore has to equal the value needed to normalize the total probability to unity. Because a Beta distribution with parameters $s+\alpha, f+\beta$ is *defined* to have this form (up to the normalization constant), $q$ *must* be that Beta distribution.

Comment: @diabel: Is my answer below acceptable, or are you looking for something else?

Answer (score 2):

In the equation:

$$ \begin{align*}
p(\left. q=x \right| s,f)
&= \frac{ {s+f \choose s} x^{s+\alpha-1}(1-x)^{f+\beta-1} / \operatorname{B}(\alpha,\beta) }{ \int_{y=0}^1 \left({s+f \choose s} y^{s+\alpha-1}(1-y)^{f+\beta-1} / \operatorname{B}(\alpha,\beta)\right) dy } \\
&= \frac{ {s+f \choose s} x^{s+\alpha-1}(1-x)^{f+\beta-1} / \operatorname{B}(\alpha,\beta) }{ {s+f \choose s} \left( \int_{y=0}^1 y^{s+\alpha-1}(1-y)^{f+\beta-1} \, dy \right) / \operatorname{B}(\alpha \, \beta) } \\
&= \frac{ x^{s+\alpha-1}(1-x)^{f+\beta-1} }{ \int_{y=0}^1 y^{s+\alpha-1}(1-y)^{f+\beta-1} \, dy }
\end{align*} $$

the denominator matches the form of the beta function:

$$ \operatorname{B}(x,y) = \int_0^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1} \, dt $$

so the denominator becomes:

$$
\int_{y=0}^1 y^{s+\alpha-1}(1-y)^{f+\beta-1} \, dy = \operatorname{B}(s+\alpha,f+\beta)
$$

and the original equation becomes:

$$
p(\left. q=x \right| s,f)
= \frac{ x^{s+\alpha-1}(1-x)^{f+\beta-1} }{ \operatorname{B}(s+\alpha,f+\beta) }
$$